# A simple equality for conditional probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space, $\mathcal G$ a sub-sigma-field, and $\mathbb P^{\mathcal G}$ denote the conditional probability.

> Is it correct that 
>   $$\int_A \mathbb P^{\mathcal G}(B)d\mathbb P = \int_B \mathbb P^{\mathcal G}(A)d\mathbb P$$
>   for all $A,B \in \mathcal F$?

This seems unintuitive to me, but the following calculation seems to confirm it:
$$\int_A \mathbb P^{\mathcal G}(B)d \mathbb P = \int \mathbb E\big[1_A\mathbb P^{\mathcal G}(B) \mid \mathcal G \big]d\mathbb P = \int \mathbb P^{\mathcal G}(B)\mathbb P^{\mathcal G}(A) d\mathbb P,$$
and similarly for $\int_B \mathbb P^{\mathcal G}(A)d\mathbb P$.

Did I make a silly mistake, or, if not, could someone give some intuition for the equality?

Comment: How did u get the first equality in the calculation that seems to confirm the result?

Comment: @d.k.o. Just $\int X d\mathbb P = \int \mathbb E(X \mid \mathcal G) d\mathbb P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true and more general form is $E[X (EY|\mathcal G)]=E[Y E(X|\mathcal G)]$ both sides being equal to $E[(E(Y|\mathcal G) (E(X|\mathcal G)]$. As you did  you only have to condition on $\mathcal G$ to get this.