# An equality for conditional probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space, $\mathcal G$ a sub-sigma-field, and $\mathbb P^{\mathcal G}$ denote the conditional probability.

[In another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535005/a-simple-equality-for-conditional-probabilities), I confirmed that for all $A,B \in \mathcal F$
$$\int_A \mathbb P^{\mathcal G}(B)d \mathbb P = \int_B \mathbb P^{\mathcal G}(A)d \mathbb P.$$

> Is it also true that for all $A,B,C \in \mathcal F$
>   $$\int_{C \cap A} \mathbb P^{\mathcal G}(B)d\mathbb P = \int_{C \cap B} \mathbb P^{\mathcal G}(A)d\mathbb P?$$

Intuitively, this seems to me like it should be true, just by applying the first result to the trace space $\{A \cap C: A \in \mathcal F\}$. But I haven't been able to convert that idea into a rigorous proof, nor have I found a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $C \in \mathcal{G}$ it is true and the proof is effectively the same as your previous question's answer.

For $C \in \mathcal{F}\setminus\mathcal{G}$, however, I don't see a reason why it ever should be true.  For instance, if $\mathcal{G} = \{\emptyset, \Omega\},$ then it becomes $$\mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{P}(A\cap C) = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B\cap C)$$
which isn't true in general.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be any two disjoint events with $P(A) >0$ and $P(B) >0$. Let $\mathcal G$ be  sigma field independent of $B $ and take $C=A$. Then RHS is $0$ and LHS is $P(A)P(B) >0$.